# Multiple X-Axis labels per column - How do I do it?

Tags: google-sheets, charts, axis-labels

I'm importing data using an API, and then dynamically updating a chart from that data.  I don't want to repeat the year.  I want to show the month as a 3 letter and year as a 4 digit.  See below example.  This requires two rows so that we only show the year at the beginning column and then when it changes.

I'm having to do this manually.  I have created breakpoint formulas in the columns in the spreadsheet so that they're only populated when the year changes, but I have NO IDEA how to create what are essentially TWO ROWS of labels like this.  Any thoughts on how I can do this most effectively, other than concatenating the two values and risking that the wrap won't work properly?

Here's a link to the graph as a reference.  You can see how the year information shows properly.

[https://sites.google.com/site/garyalankanofsky?usp=sharing](https://sites.google.com/site/garyalankanofsky/home)

I'd welcome any suggestions! Thanks!!

Gary

I haven't succeeded yet with this.

Comment: I appreciate your note . but the question does stand on it's own.  How can you create TWO ROWS of X-Axis Labels, where one row has EVERY month and one row only has the YEAR when it changes?  I think you may have reacted to the fact that I said "see below" a couple of times but the question is clear: "I have NO IDEA how to create what are essentially TWO ROWS of labels...".     Is it a TOS violation for me to refer to a provided visual reference?  Because if so, I was unaware.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a given format for X-axis Chart values for a period covering 12 months:

- all month values are to show a 3 letter Name only.
- except for the first and the last month where there are two additional criteria:

  - Year is included "YYYY"
  - a line break should appear between the Month name and the Year

The solution is to create an additional row/column (depending on the orientation of the data) and convert date values to text:

- Month 1 & 12: `=TEXT(B1,"mmm")&CHAR(10)&TEXT(B1,"YYYY")`

  - where B1 is the date field for the relevant month
- Months 2 - 11 (inclusive): `=TEXT(B1,"mmm")`

  - where "B1" is the date field for the relevant month

In the following example,

- Sheet1 shows the standard chart outcome (whether data has a Vertical or Horizontal orientation)
- Chart shows the result when using X-Axis labels created by converting date values to text.

Values on "Chart" are obtained from "Sheet1" as follows:

- Data

  - Horizontal: `=transpose(indirect(address(match($B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$16,0),1,4,true,"Sheet1")&":"&address((match($B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$16,0))+11,1,4,true)))`
  - Vertical: `=indirect(address(match($B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$16,0),1,4,true,"Sheet1")&":"&address((match($B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$16,0))+11,1,4,true))`
- Dates

  - Horizontal: `=transpose(indirect(address(match($B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$16,0),2,4,true,"Sheet1")&":"&address((match($B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$16,0))+11,2,4,true)))`
  - Vertical: `=indirect(address(match($B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$16,0),2,4,true,"Sheet1")&":"&address((match($B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$16,0))+11,2,4,true))`

---

**Sheet1 - standard X-Axis**

[image: sheet1]

---

**Chart - Custom X-Axis**

[image: after]